# When user logged out and the push notification come my app opens automatically. i want to open my app on the click of push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

This is the method by which i am sending the push notification :-

```
 private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        Intent intentblank = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intentblank.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentblank);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        Log.e("message.....", msg);


        if (msg.equals("You Have got New Message")) {

            Log.e("msg occuring..", "intent enter in message...");
            intent.putExtra("KEYMESSAGE", "Message");

        } else {

            Log.e("notification occuring..", "notification occurs.....");
            intent.putExtra("KEYNOTIFICATION", "aman");


        }



        if (sharedPreferencesUtilities.getEmail().equals("") || sharedPreferencesUtilities.getPassword().equals("")) {
            Log.e("blank notification....", "blank notification...........................");
            contentIntent  =PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentblank, 0);
        } else {
           contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }


        mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentTitle("Telepoh")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        mBuilder.setOngoing(false);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());


    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.push_icon : R.drawable.push_icon;
    }
}
```

I want that when the user logged out then on the click on the push notification the login page is open of my app. But in my case if the user logged out then the app is open automatically. I want to do it on the click of the push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove below line of code

```
 startActivity(intentblank);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always call the login activity on notification click. In the login activity check if the user is logged in or not. If logged in move to main activity or else stay on login activity

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, loginIntent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And put your   `startActivity(loginIntent );` inside your condition for login check.